# How to copy a .xml file to a zip folder?

Tags: powershell, zip

i am trying to move or copy a .xml file  into a zip folder.

```
Move-Item-Path "C:\Users\1469\Desktop\folder1\archive.xml" -Destination "C:\Users\1469\Desktop\*.zip" -Force
```

But this code is not working. please help me!

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in that line (`Move-Item-Path` should be `Move-Item -Path`). You can't use wildcards in a destination path, though, and you also can't use `Move-Item` to move files into zip files. Doing so would simply overwrite the zip file with the XML file.

You need the [`Shell.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object for adding files to a zip file:

```
$zip = 'C:\Users\1469\Desktop\your.zip'
$xml = 'C:\Users\1469\Desktop\folder1\archive.xml'

(New-Object -COM Shell.Application).NameSpace($zip).CopyHere($xml)
```

Note that the zip file must already exist. It won't be created automatically.